# Log HTTP communications in java without external tools

Tags: java, http, mobile, java-me, logging

Is it possible (through APIs) to log HTTP communications from within a java ME based application without using any external tools. I am looking at some kind of a hook that will allow some code to be run before and after every HTTP communication.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [java.lang.instrument](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html) package to alter the `java.net.URLConnection` and/or `java.net.Socket` classes might fit your need, if you'd consider the instrumentation agent to not be an "external tool" because it runs inside of the same JVM as what your'e monitoring.

Comment: From what i understood. Instrument is not available in MircroEdition

Comment: MicroMeulator (http://www.microemu.org/) is an implementation of Java ME in Java SE, which would let you use instrumentation.  It'd also let you use standard profiling tools.  Don't know if testing in an emulator would meet your needs, though.

Comment: certainly looks interesting. But i'd like to test on real device as well. Would it be possible to do something similar by implementing a wrapper around default javax.microedition.io.HttpConnection implementation

Comment: Well, if the only thing you're logging is your own code, you can of course wrap all of the net-related classes in your code.  Same goes if there's third party code making connections, but you can supply it with a factory object which generates the connections/sockets/etc.  But if neither of those conditions apply then you need something like instrumentation.